# How to create a (half) dynamic array of characters in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

For what I am trying to do, I require an array in the form `char **`.
I found out that using the following creates a dynamic array that ends up requiring 256 free calls:

```
char** start = malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0;i<256;i++) {
    start[i] = malloc(11*sizeof(char));
}
for (i=0;i<256;i++) {
    free(start[i]);
}
```

How do I create an array that is in the form `char[(malloc)][(12)]` if that makes sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char (*p)[12] = calloc(n, sizeof(*p));  // or malloc

...

free(p);
```

`p` is a pointer to `n` arrays, each of length 12.

Comment: I was confused at first by how different the answer looked from char **, but once I actually tried exactly what you suggested, worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @user1190885: Ah sorry, I didn't notice that you were using `char`!  I've adjusted my answer anyway.